# Linked list curr.nextval and curr.dataval explanation

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I'm new to programming and am a bit confused with where these variables are coming from. This is part of codecedmy Linked List tutorial. variable in question are curr.nextval and curr.dataval as highlighted in bold in the code snippet below.

```
def append(self, dataval):
    
    """Insert a new element at the end of the list."""
    
    if not self.head:
        self.head = Node(dataval=dataval)
        return
    
    curr = self.head
    
    **while curr.nextval:**
        **curr = curr.nextval**
        
    curr.nextval = Node(dataval=dataval)
    
def add_after(self, middle_dataval, dataval):
    
    """Insert a new element after the node with middle_dataval"""
    
    if middle_dataval is None:
        print("Data to insert after not specified")
        return
    
    curr = self.head
    
    while curr and **curr.dataval** != middle_dataval:
        curr = **curr.nextval**
        
    new_node = Node(dataval = dataval)
    
    new_node.nextval = curr.nextval
    curr.nextval = new_node
```

Trying to understand what these variable declaration mean and where it coming from.